# snap.svg save svg to png

Tags: javascript, svg, png, snap.svg

I am creating a Snap.svg app where users can basically add blocks and manipulate them then save it to a png. The blocks are all drawn in inches.  I have code that calculates the device PPI and that is used to draw the blocks, it gets calculated to 96 PPI.  This all works fine except that when I save the SVG to a PNG it is saved with 72 PPI so then the save PNG is larger than what it should be.

I am using this [JavaScript Library](https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL) to save the SVG as a PNG.

So my question is how do I get around this issue?

Comment: did you find a solution? i would be also interested in this question

Comment: Yes, I am using this library: https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL it works really well.

Answer (score 5):

I am using this library: https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL it works really well.

This is the code I ended up with that works for me.

```
// Get the SVG element
var svg = document.getElementById("design-1");

svg.toDataURL("image/png", {
    callback : function(data) {
        // Convert image to 'octet-stream' (Just a download, really)
        var image = data.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        window.location.href = image;
    }
});
```

Comment: So how did you solve the question you posed? Please post the steps here and accept the answer.